# .gitignore not ignoring files inside folder

Tags: git, gitignore

I have a folder named = **Hackerrank** inside there are some files I want to ignore into version control, So I add files into .gitignore file but changes are reflected into version control, .gitnore not working. I add `HackerRank/whiteBoard.py` to ignore file

**GitHub Directory**

[image]

**Changes are showing on source control**

[image]

Comment: Have you commited this `whiteBoard.py` file **before** you added it in the `.gitignore`?

Answer (score 1):

If you already versioned that file in a commit prior your modification to .gitignore, that file is tracked and will be tracked.

In that case, you have to remove the file from versioning before updating .gitignore. Please refer to duplicate question for more details: [How to make git forget about a file that was tracked but is now in gitignore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1274057/how-to-make-git-forget-about-a-file-that-was-tracked-but-is-now-in-gitignore)